# How to add filename when importing multiple Excel files in R?

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R and learning as I go. I'm trying to import a series of Excel files and then export them as one single file. The code below works fine for that. However, I cannot figure out how to add a filename to each row of the data that corresponds to the filename it came from. The filenames are in a pattern "YYYYMMDD-....." and I would like to crop that so only the YYYYMMDD is saved as the filename.

```
*# Import series of files from Excel
library(readxl)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xls')
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)

# Combine all Excel files into one dataframe
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")

# Export to Excel
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df,"my file path goes here")
```

Any help you can provide would really help me from throwing my laptop across the room! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your vector of file names, `file.list`, looks something like this:

```
file.list <- c("20200101-foo1.xls", "20210101-foo2.xls")
```

The trick is to make `df.list` a named list. You can use `stringr::str_replace` to make the YYYYMMDD names. In this example, remove everything from the "-" onwards:

```
library(stringr)
file.list %>% str_replace("-.+", "")
[1] "20200101" "20210101"
```

So supply the names to the list like this:

```
names(df.list) <- file.list %>% 
  str_replace("-.+", "")
```

And now `bind_rows` with the `.id` argument will create a column with the names:

```
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "filename")
```

Answer (score 1):

should be fairly straight forward:

```r
library(readxl)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xls')
df <- map_dfr( file.list, ~ read_excel(.x) %>% mutate( File = str_match( .x, "\\d{8}" )[,1] ) )
```

Note I don't have a set of xls files to try this on.

Comment: I did have to add library(dplyr) or I got an error on the 'mutate' command. Once I added that library, it worked great and is very effiicient! thank you!

Comment: ah yes, I often take for granted that dplyr is loaded. one shoultn't.